# Stopping selenium 4 in C# on specific network response string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I am experimenting selenium 4 on c#, and I'm having some trouble, I have a program that currently loads multiple pages, one every 10 seconds, that have a simple "?page=i" pattern and scrapes their network activity. I'm achieving this with a simple "for i" loop, but I'd like it to run infinitely until a network request with a very specific string is made. Is this possible?

Some code for context:

```
var opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.AddArgument("--headless");
opt.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<V113.DevToolsSessionDomains>();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();
domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
await domains.Network.Enable(new V113.Network.EnableCommandSettings());
for(int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Page {i}");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"url/?page={i}");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
driver.Quit();
Console.WriteLine("Chromium quit.");
```

Comment: Looping until a certain condition is easy using a [while statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-while-statement), however we need more information about the specific condition you are trying to detect, including your code trials used to detect this special string.

Comment: Basically, we need to see enough code for a [repro].